# What speaks against static fields?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static, static-members

I have two cases in our tool where I have some difficulties in my integration tests with static fields. In the application these fields are no problem. In my tests I create basically a new application with each test method. When I run these in one test run, you can imagine, there will be some problems. First let me show two such cases.

**Case 1**

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static IService service;

    public static void Initialize(IService service)
    {
        SomeClass.service = service;
    }

    public void DoSomthing()
    {
        service.Foo();
    }
}
```

Basically objects of this class will be created in huge numbers. To be able to use the `IService` object it is stored as an static field.
In my tests this is a problem because the `IService` is actually an `IServiceProvider` and a service is retrieved only once in the first test. In the second test the service of the first test is used.
In the real application there is only one `IService` or `IServiceProvider`. Therefor we do not have a problem here.

**Case 2**

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    private static readonly Lazy<SpecificClass> specificClass = new Lazy<SpecificClass>(() => new SpecificClass());

    public static SpecificClass SpecificClass
    {
        get { return specificClass.Value; }
    }
}

class SpecificClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

This is even more troublesome for my tests, because even if I create a complete new application, when the `SpecificClass` was used in the first test it is the same object in the second test.
In my tests I have a memory leak here, because the `SpecificClass` has a list where it remembers objects from the first test. With each tests more and more objects are added to the list.
In the real application the list is filled only once on application startup. So no memory leak here.

I know, that tests typically show design flaws, but I cannot see one here. The only argument for removing these static fields I can think of is, that my tests do not work otherwise.

So my question now, why is it in these to cases considered bad code to use the static fields or is it not? I do not want to know solutions for these cases. I only need a justification why a change in the code is required other than "I cannot test it properly."

Comment: It all depends on what your class does. Does it have a state (Properties which are changing?) In this case you have problem with isolated tests. If it has literally static operations (like a+b) that its not a problem at all. Pehaps you can describe moredetailed what the excat problem is

Comment: Basically, static fields lead to global state. That's okay for genuine constants, but in your case you want multiple tests to have their own state, which means you need them to be isolated from each other. Global state works against that.

Comment: @JonSkeet I  know why they are bad for my tests. But that is no accepted argument as long as it works for the real application. That is why I want to find a different argument.

Comment: What speaks against letting each instance of `SomeClass` have their own reference to `IService` (provided via constructor => dependency injection) instead of a shared reference? All the references could still point to the same instance of `IService`. The only thing is, that you don't have a convenient(?) way to change that reference for all instances of `SomeClass` at once (`Initialize`). But if you *need* that, you could work with a thin wrapper around the actual `IService` instance.

Comment: @Corak Nothing speaks against this solution. Only the responsable person does not see the need to change it. That is why I am looking for a valid argument.

Comment: @Yggdrasil - Oh, you're looking for an argument against this, okay. Well, not being able to straightforward write tests for this should be a strong enough argument in of itself. Hard to test code is bad by definition. And the burden of defending should lie on the other side. You can write much more horrible code that "works", but that should never be an argument not to refactor.

Comment: @Corak I do not think I can agree with this. One example: It is bad code to have a dependency of a concrete class. I could argument, that with this I cannot write unit tests for this class. But I can also argument that it is not flexible enough. You cannot change the implementation without refactoring this class. You cannot split the dependency, because it has two responsibilities without refactoring the original class.

Answer (score 3):

The design flaw here is a *component* decides the life-cycle of its dependencies, which is bad both in the actual application and it makes things harder when coding tests.

What you need is using an inversion of control container with dependency injection support, and let it decide by configuration injected dependencies' life cycle.

For example, in [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/) it would be configured as follows:

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register
(
     Component.For<SomeClass>().LifeStyleTransient(),
     Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<SomeService>().LifeStyleSingleton()
);
```

So you're deciding that `IService` is a singleton by configuration but your code relies on that instances of `SomeClass` will get injected an instance of an implementation of `IService`.

> Why is it bad for the actual application. I only need a justification
>   why a change in the code is necessary.

- **No EASY unit testing**: you can't use automatic dependency injection if you don't use instance constructors and/or properties. This makes your code harder to test, because a simple configuration can't inject a *fake* instead of an actual implementation.
- **No automatic dependency injection**. Different applications and services can't be configured to use same or different dependency interface implementations and you lose a **big feature: object life-cycle (transient, singleton, per-request, per-thread) could be defined by configuration and you code shouldn't be aware about this.**
- **No single responsibility principle**. Is your class responsible of deciding the life-cycle of its dependencies, or isn't the framework which should define it?

You said to Jon Skeet in some comment in your question:

> @JonSkeet I know why they are bad for my tests. But that is no
>   accepted argument as long as it works for the real application. That
>   is why I want to find a different argument. –

**Software quality is as real as the actual application**. If developing quality software isn't an accepted argument for you, maybe you need to get back to the roots and find **why an application or service must be testable**.

Comment: Why is it bad for the actual application. I only need a justification why a change in the code is necessary.

Comment: @Yggdrasil Check my update, At the end of the day, with all my respects, my humble opinion is you want to convince yourself about *why not* instead of embrancing a better development strategy.

Comment: Fidemraizer I do not need to convince myself. I would change it right away or better I would have programmed it differently from the start. But this is not my code and in our company you can only ask the owner of the code to change it. If you change it yourself you will be responsible for every defect to come.
With your argumentation I can justify the change of case 2. In case 1 the lifecycle of IService still lies by the component framework. It is also easy to unit test this class - I can mock IService. And I can change the implementation.

Comment: I am sorry if I somehow upset you. It was definitely not my intention. I would still appreciate your opinion on my edited comment about case 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a valid use case for all objects that are not suitable candidates for dependency injection (ORM entities are an example).

An alternative to static fields in those cases is providing the dependencies as method arguments:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething(IService service)
    {
        service.Foo();
    }
}
```

One of advantages of this approach, besides easier testing, is that you don't have to take care to properly initialize static state manually (which may sometimes be difficult to achieve and especially difficult to maintain afterwards when static dependencies start depending on each other, because of order in which static fields are initialized, etc).

Also, refactoring and changing code in the future is easier because you don't have to move/duplicate static field definitions and initializations when you decide to extract the logic that uses them into separate class, etc.